# Get API to return "Other (please specify)" in the user's language

Tags: api, surveymonkey

We have a survey in Spanish with a single-response question with an "Other" option. To the user it appears in their language eg "Otra (especifique)" for Spanish. But in the get_survey_details API, while the regular options are returned in the local language, this option is returned in English:

`..."answers":{"other":{"id":"875283442","visible":true,"is_answer_choice":true,"apply_all_rows":false,"text":"Other (please specify)","position":0,"num_chars":50,"error_text":"Please enter a comment.","num_lines":1},"choices":[{"visible":true,"text"...etc...`

How can I get back what the user sees?

Comment: No, right now there isn't a way to pull a translation for those fields. There is functionality in the works for handling translations better through the API but as of right now translations are unavailable.

Comment: Thanks GK but I didn't think I was asking for a translation,  simply to return what the user sees just like all the other options that download as presented.

Comment: Yes, what the user sees is actually not stored in SurveyMonkey at all, it's handled by a third party service on page load (smartling). So it can't be made available through the API.